# Magento 2.3 requirejs-config.js is empty on production mode

Tags: magento2, production-mode, requirejs-config.js, not-found

After setting Magento 2 to production mode, Magento generated all the static files in **pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US** except for the **requirejs-config.min.js** file, the file exists but **its empty** and some js files are returning **404** in browser, copying the generated file from when the server was on **default** mode (generated on the fly) and pasting it in **requirejs-config.min.js** once the server is on **production** mode, fixes the **404** files issue but the solution is a hack. any idea why Magento is not generating the file in any directory **(fr_FR,en_US)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your store is in production mode so you have to run deploy command for each language using this command : **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR**

if this will not work then,

Please try to generate log by push your store in developer mode so you will get all error logs.

If this helps then hit like.

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: thank you, I didn't think of using the "setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR" command because setting Magento 2 on production mode (deploy:mode:set production) does the same thing(generates the files) but somehow the requirejs.config is only generated using (setup:static-content:deploy)